# See if you can spot the bug -- Beginner error in Quicksort

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I'm a beginner trying to write a set of quicksort functions and getting a segmentation fault (core dumped).

My recursive quicksort function is supposed to call the helper quicksort function which

1. calls the partition function to do most of the actual work and
2. calls itself to deal with sub-arrays recursively:

I've been looking at this for hours and trying to find the bug(s) causing this. Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Thank you in advance for being an awesome, kind of human being.

[x86 AT&T syntax]

```
    .text
    .globl  quicksort
quicksort:

#subroutine prologue
    pushl %ebp      #store stack frame of calling function on stack.
    movl %esp, %ebp     # use current stack pointer for called function

    #subroutine main body
    movl 8(%ebp), %edi  # ptr to array          in edi
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx # num elements          in ecx

    jl quicksort_help   # CHECK
    ret

quicksort_help:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax
    jle     exit
    subl    $4, %esp
    pushl   16(%ebp)
    pushl   12(%ebp)
    pushl   8(%ebp)
    call    partition
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    decl    %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   12(%ebp)
    pushl   8(%ebp)
    call    quicksort
    addl    $16, %esp
    subl    $4, %esp
    pushl   16(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    incl    %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   8(%ebp)
    call    quicksort
    addl    $16, %esp

exit:
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: I'd start by commenting the body of the function; oftentimes, just writing out what you *mean* to do can point out where what you are *actually* doing is different.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #subroutine prologue
>     pushl %ebp      #store stack frame of calling function on stack.
>     movl %esp, %ebp     # use current stack pointer for called function
>     #subroutine main body
>     movl 8(%ebp), %edi  # ptr to array          in edi
>     movl 12(%ebp), %ecx # num elements          in ecx
> *** HERE IS SOMETHING MISSING ***
>     jl quicksort_help   # CHECK
>     ret
> ```

The `jl` instruction will jump only on the LESS condition, but the code does not contain any instructions that actually define this condition!

Comment: Do you think it would be better to change it to 'jmp' or to add the condition beforehand?

Comment: @a2239 Why did you put the JL instruction there? What purpose did you think it served?